# how to get mouse coordinates in a form builder 6

Tags: c++builder

i want to use the coordinates of the mouse on a form and calculate the distance between the cursor and some other point.

but the codes i have found only give you the coordinates on the whole screen.. not 
on the form.
i also have found that you can convert, between the coordinates of the screen to the coordinates of the form but how do i do it?

i havent found examples that actually work

by the way the function *ScreenToClient* says undefined symbol hWnd...

Answer (score 2):

If you call the Win32 API `ScreenToClient()` function, you have to provide it with an `HWND`, eg:

```
POINT Pt = Mouse->CursorPos;
Pt = ::ScreenToClient(this->Handle, &Pt);
```

However, VCL UI controls also have their own `ScreenToClient()` method inherited from `TWinControl`, eg:

```
TPoint Pt = this->ScreenToClient(Mouse->CursorPos);
```

Comment: Pt := Mouse.CursorPos;
Pt := Windows.ScreenToClient(Handle, Pt);
gave me this error 
E2070: unvalid use of namespace ´Windows´

Comment: Did you add `Windows` to your `uses` clause?

Comment: My bad, I did not notice you were using C++.  I gave you a Delphi solution.  I updated my answer.