# How to get Mouse location in a form of builder 6

Tags: mouse, c++builder

i want to use the location of the mouse on a form and use the distance between the cursor and some other point.

but the codes i have found only give you the coordinates on the whole screen..witch won´t work because it is nos relative to the form.. i also have found that you can convert, between the coordinates of the screen to the coordinates of the form but how do i do it?

i havent found examples that actually work

by the way the function ScreenToClient says undefined symbol hWnd...

Comment: ubication?  Do you mean location?

Comment: yes i do... english is not my lenguage...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get mouse coordinates in a form builder 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828265/how-to-get-mouse-coordinates-in-a-form-builder-6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ScreenToClient function for that:

```
TPoint p = Mouse->CursorPos;
Form1->ScreenToClient(p);
ShowMessage("Mouse-Left relative to Form: "+IntToStr((int)p.x));
ShowMessage("Mouse-Top relative to Form: "+IntToStr((int)p.x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ScreenToClient` method, but in the following way:

```
TPoint p_rel_scr = Mouse->CursorPos;
TPoint p_rel_frm = Form1->ScreenToClient(p_rel_scr );
int x_position = (int) p_rel_frm.x;
int y_position = (int) p_rel_frm.y;
```

Where `p_rel_scr` is a position relative to the upper left corner of the screen and `p_rel_frm` relative to the form.